# System Center Configuration manager Push Notification with read receipents

Tags: push-notification, sccm, system-center

We need to push Push Pop up notifications for ex: “urgent message to warn users” and also generate a report on the success rate as to how many users in the network received it and read it, how many users did not receive it or did not read it.

Microsoft has suggested to use SCCM Power Schell scripting to send Client notifications with close button to confirm receive.

Is there any other way of accomplishing it through SCCM without any customization?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered pushing a VBScript to all clients which displays the message? If the user clicks "OK" to say they've read and understood the message then it could exit with a return code of 0, otherwise it could return a 1. It's then trivial to report each computer's success result in SCCM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain how can i push a simple text messages to client machines ? Secondly If I add some VB script and return values then is there any SCCM builtin report to show the results for all clients ?

Comment: Create a package with the VBScript for the message in the source and create a program with the command line "wscript.exe yourscriptfile.vbs". For information on showing simple messages in VBScript see http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/08/16/how-can-i-give-a-user-a-yes-no-prompt.aspx. There are reports that show success failure rates of adverts, but you may want to make a custom one for this purpose.